# How to change z-level of an individual UIBarButtonItem (iOS)

Tags: ios, rendering, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a couple of custom `UIBarButtonItem`s (with custom subviews) in a navigation bar which overlap to a degree sometimes. This is fine and the intended behaviour, except sometimes one element renders underneath one on top of which I would like it to render. How can I tweak the z-level of these elements so they render properly?

The one which is improperly rendering on top is also a stock `UIBarButtonSystemItem`, if that makes a difference.

Comment: You have no control of the z-order of the buttons in a navbar (or toolbar). You can dig into the private subview structure and reorder the views but every time a user taps on one, the order may change.

Comment: Have you tried the methods `bringSubviewToFront:` and `sendSubviewToBack:`?